# How do I dynamically access .yml values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have following in rv.yml file:

```
:server1:
   :abc: ['ABC',1]
   :def: ['DEF',2]
   :ghi: ['GHI',3]
   :jkl: ['JKL',4]

 :server2:
   :abc: ['ABC',4]
   :def: ['DEF',2]
   :ghi: ['GHI',1]
   :jkl: ['JKL',3]
```

I am storing the server values and left part of the array in a variable during runtime. Eg: server_name = server1 (dynamic) and prop_values = abc[1]. If I want to access abc[1] of server1 it should return 1, so I can use Test::data.env.server1.abc[1] but I want to dynamically pass the values ('server1' and abc[1]). How do I do this? Using following does not give what I want:

```
Test::data.env[server_name][prop_values]
```

I want it to resolve and get me the actual value in .yml file using ruby

Comment: I don't see how `Test::data.env.server1.abc[1]` would return you `4`.

Comment: > If I want to access abc[1] of server1 it should return 4
Did you mean `abc[1]` of `server2`? What exactly is the problem? Are you already loading the data via `YAML.load`?

Comment: Test::data.env (disregard this part) - so this resolves into accessing rv.yml file and when I traverse inside based on server1 as key I want to get the value at 2nd index of the array.

Comment: yes I am loading the yml but I dont want to hard code server1 or server 2 it will be decided during runtime. abc[1] from sever1 should return 1

Comment: "following does not give what I want" - what _does_ it give you then? What is `prop_values`? What type is `Test::data.env`? What does it return from its `#[]` method? How does _that_ thing handle `#[]`? Some hints for research.

Comment: uninitialized constant Test::Data::AbstractProps::NoSuchConfigProp (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we create **load_custom.rb** for access the custom **.yml** file:

**config/initializers/load_config.rb**

```
CONFIG_PATH="#{Rails.root}/config/rv.yml"
RV_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(CONFIG_PATH)
```

Then we create **rv.yml** file in config folder like the below:

**./config/rv.yml**

```
server1:
   abc: ['ABC',1]
   def: ['DEF',2]
   ghi: ['GHI',3]
   jkl: ['JKL',4]

server2:
  abc: ['ABC',4]
  def: ['DEF',2]
  ghi: ['GHI',1]
  jkl: ['JKL',3]
```

And now, we can access like the below:

```
server_name = 'server1'
RV_CONFIG[server_name]
```

result:

> {"abc"=>["ABC", 1], "def"=>["DEF", 2], "ghi"=>["GHI", 3],
>   "jkl"=>["JKL", 4]}

---

```
RV_CONFIG[server_name]['abc']
```

result:

> ["ABC", 1]

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing but it didn’t work

Comment: uninitialized constant AbstractProps::NoSuchConfigProp (NameError)

Comment: What is your Rails version? Could you try this usage with new rails project?  I tried this usage in my project and works perfectly.

Comment: I am using Rails 5.1.4

Comment: Have you tried this usage with new rails application?